# Rails in a subdirectory behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, reverse-proxy

I don't get it. I tried to run a Rails app behind an apache reverse proxy. I'm using Unicorn on port 8080.

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -p 8080
```

Apache VirtualHost

```
ProxyPass /foo/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/ http://localhost:8080/
```

This basically works. A request to http://domain.tld/foo/ arrives at the Rails app. What follows is a redirect to an authentication mechanism using the following in `ApplicationController.before_filter`:

```
redirect_to controller: 'sessions', action: 'index'
```

As expected, I will be redirected to http://domain.tld/sessions/. Now I'd like to configure Rails to redirect to http://domain.tld/foo/sessions/ globally, without explicitly mentioning it with every redirect.

I tried using this in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.relative_url_root = '/foo'
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/foo'
```

And starting Unicorn with this:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/foo' bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -p 8080
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. It doesn't change the behaviour at all. I've added debug output before the redirect to see, what's going on.

```
puts Rails.application.config.relative_url_root
puts ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
puts url_for controller: 'sessions', action: 'index'
```

This prints out:

```
/foo
/foo
http://domain.tld/sessions
```

Can anybody tell me why Rails does not take the configuration into account?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've got the solution. I had to change the apache config to this

```
ProxyPass /foo/ http://localhost:8080/foo/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/ http://localhost:8080/foo/
```

and config.ru to this

```
if Rails.env.production?
  map '/foo' do
    run Rails.application
  end
else
  run Rails.application
end
```